# How to recover files from a hard drive that fell down

Tags: external-hard-drive

My external hard drive fell down two days ago and since then, if i connect it to my computer it would not be visible. it stopped spinning but making funny beeps. i'll be very glad if anyone can assist me.

Comment: How much is the information worth? Tens of dollars? Thousands of dollars? If the latter, send it to a data recovery service. If the former, write it off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If  the funny beeps originate from the mechanical parts of the hard drive then the best solution would be a data recovery service (when you google the term you’re bound to get several results back). It’s a bit cheaper when you approach them as an individual rather than as a company but unfortunately they still charge an arm, leg, one kidney and claim prima nocta.  So it’s up to you to determine if the price is worth the data

My personal experience with opening the hard drive myself and trying to nudge the head back into place are … less than successful.  And some data recovery services will charge extra when you first tried it yourself and then send it in for recovery.

If it’s only electronics (power supply buzzing for example) you can try to !!VERY CAREFULLY!! (disclaimer about electrical hazards and such) replace suspected malfunctioning parts with those of an identical model. It’s not that hard but you have to know what you’re doing … and be comfortable with the possibility that not only the attempt might fail but also that the working identical model won’t function anymore.

Kind regards,
Wim